# typings installs every definition twice

Tags: typescript, tsd

when I install definition files with typings, two definition files are created: One of them in typings/browser and the other in typings/main.
Why does this happen and how do I prevent it, because it causes many Dublciate identifier exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add either add the `browser` directory and definition file, or the `main` directory and definition file to the exclude section of your `tscofing.json` file to eliminate the errors. Like so:

```
exclude: ["typings/browser", "typings/browser.d.ts"]
```

or

```
exclude: ["typings/main", "typings/main.d.ts"]
```

In short, this is so that developers can expose different sets of functionality for browser and non-browser TypeScript applications.

Comment: Thanks a lot I already added "typings/browser" to the exclude list but I didn't add "typings/browser.d.ts"